# Mouse cursor not snapping to mesh

Tags: mesh, mouse

Recently when I grab a mesh in blender my mouse does not snap to it. What I mean is that the mouse cursor stays where it's at and moves the mesh from a distance. I don't know how this happened but I would like to know how to change it back.

Comment: Can you share an image of your viewport on what happens?

Comment: Ckeck preferences, It looks like offset is on.